# Ubuntu on armhf: "using PPAs with apt-get source -b"?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository

In brief, the problem I seem to be having is that apt-get "ignores" whatever PPA I add. I assume that this is because the respective PPA's limit their debs to i386 and AMD64 builds. (I'm using armhf.) This causes a problem though. I'd like to use "apt-get source -b" to build the respective debs. However, even when enabling the PPA's deb-src repository, apt-cache policy still doesn't "find" the respective packages. I'm forced to download the packages, configure/make/checkinstall.

Am I correct in thinking I should be able to compile these packages on arm via "apt-get source -b"?  If so, how do I **force** ubuntu to load these repositories? That is, how do I stop apt-get from "IGN"oring these PPAs?

Comment: Have you tried adding either i386 or amd64 as foreign architectures? The packages might show up then. Those "Ign" don't mean what you think they mean. When apt sees that a package list hasn't been updated, it ignores it, instead of wasting bandwidth downloading it again.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Ign means there was am error: http://superuser.com/a/454874/334516 I still think the best bet is adding a foreign architecture using `dpkg`.

Comment: Thanks Muru, I've **just** been researching this option. What I'm still researching is how, in the process of using apt-get to compile from a source file, one can make sure any dependencies are drawn from the right repository (**not** amd64 or i386). I suppose the brute force method might be to remove the "arch" setting once the source file has been downloaded?

Comment: The other brute force method would be getting the build-depends package list and specifying the architecture (`package:arch`).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've tried this method and it works. :-) For the next person who stumbles on this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:(name of PPA)
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache policy (package name) #Just to make sure it's there 
sudo apt-get source -b (package name) 
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture amd64 #Do this whether the package compiles correctly or not
sudo apt-get update
```

At this point, if the package didn't compile due to missing dependencies, it's safe to install them (that is, there's no chance they will be drawn from the wrong architecture/repository). They shouldn't anyway, but this is insurance.

```
sudo apt-get source -b (package name) #if necessary
```

Once you've successfully compiled, look for the `armhf` deb file in your current directory (the folder you've been working in) and: `sudo dpkg -i (package name).deb`.

*So... there may be a more elegant way to accomplish this, but I leave that to more knowledgeable users.*

**Note:** Packages installed this way will **not** update automatically. You will have to remove the original package, compile the updated package yourself, and re-install. As long as you don't purge the original installation, all of your preferences should be retained.

Comment: You could also ask the PPA maintainer if he/she would consider requesting armhf builds. The requirements are on [this](https://dev.launchpad.net/CommunityARMBuilds) page.